# How to fix the CSS error on the server MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have uploaded my MVC 5 web application to the server. Now, the problem is, the css files are not being attached properly. However, the same files are running smoothly on localhost without any error.
When I check the HTML on the server it gives me following output for CSS links.

```
<link href="/Content/assets?v=4n6kYPUkUwu7tZn3MsrSy36B6LTr1hkXANlpMWod7i41" 
rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/sitestyle?v=xoKL3H2b97OA1a-zgCd7hHEEvNdFOWSJNNKSxyVfc0c1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I would appreciate any help in this regards,
Thanks.

Comment: Are you running your website within a folder? Also, how are you creating the tags within your code?

Comment: using bundles, and I have published my website using normal publish method (Custom) in VS2015

Comment: in your bundles is BundleTable.EnableOptimizations set? And for is it within a folder I mean has the site been installed straight onto an IP/Domain (mytest.test), or is it within a sub folder (mytest.test/testsite/)?

Comment: What @jjr2000 means to ask is, Are you publishing your site to the root of the site, or are you publishing it to a folder within the site?  Meaning example.com or example.com/subfolder/?

Comment: No I haven't set this. 
and it is installed in the HomeDirectory/Httpdocs/MySite

Comment: Thanks for explanation @ErikFunkenbusch

Comment: @Aleem - There is a difference between where a site lives in the directory structure of the server (C:\Sites\whatever...) and where the site is published in the URL(http://example.com/whatever).  Does the URL to your site refer to a subfolder within the site or the root of the site?

Comment: It refers to the subfolder within my site:
HomeDirectory/httpdocs/Views/Home/Index

I am sorry If I am not getting what you are trying to ask, This is my first experience with publishing MVC 5 Entity framework website.

Comment: Thanks @jjr2000, I have set the BundleTable.EnableOptimizations. It worked for me. :)

Comment: I'll drop it as an answer for future reference in case anyone else stumbles upon this post

Answer (score 0):

With bundler issues, it can often help to set

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

This works by telling the bundler to compile the code into one file which is optimized for publishing purposes.